# How to call AsyncTask class in the fragment class, when i call is not go in the AsyncTask it will return null view what i do?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

How to call AsyncTask class in the fragment class, when i call is not go in the AsyncTask it will return null view what i do ? And my view is created in postExecute afetr i got all the data from doInbackground.

public class ShowResultsFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

```
Context context;

ArrayList<Semester> semesterArrayList;

LayoutInflater inflaterView;

ViewGroup containerView;

View newView;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    this.inflaterView = inflater;
    this.containerView = container;
    context = container.getContext();

   new StudentResultAsyncTask().execute();

    return newView;
}
```

public class StudentResultAsyncTask extends AsyncTask {

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;

    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    String jsondata = "{\"1\" :[{\"subName\":\"EG\",\"subCode\":\"1009\",\"subCredit\":\"5\",\"subGrade\":\"AA\"}," +
            "{\"subName\":\"ES\",\"subCode\":\"2009\",\"subCredit\":\"6\",\"subGrade\":\"DD\"}," +
            "{\"subName\":\"EME\",\"subCode\":\"3009\",\"subCredit\":\"6\",\"subGrade\":\"FF\"}," +
            "{\"subName\":\"EEE\",\"subCode\":\"4009\",\"subCredit\":\"7\",\"subGrade\":\"BC\"}," +
            "{\"subName\":\"MOS\",\"subCode\":\"5009\",\"subCredit\":\"6\",\"subGrade\":\"FF\"}," +
            "{\"subName\":\"M-1\",\"subCode\":\"1009\",\"subCredit\":\"6\",\"subGrade\":\"CD\"}," +
            "{\"subName\":\"EE\",\"subCode\":\"45090\",\"subCredit\":\"4\",\"subGrade\":\"AB\"}," +
            "{\"subName\":\"ECE\",\"subCode\":\"10090\",\"subCredit\":\"5\",\"subGrade\":\"FF\"}," +
            "{\"SPI\":\"1.4\",\"CPI\":\"4.67\"}]," +
            "\"2\":[{\"subName\":\"M-2\",\"subCode\":\"111009\",\"subCredit\":\"6\",\"subGrade\":\"DD\"}," +
            "{\"subName\":\"Workshop\",\"subCode\":\"1009\",\"subCredit\":\"6\",\"subGrade\":\"AB\"}," +
            "{\"subName\":\"CPU\",\"subCode\":\"1009\",\"subCredit\":\"6\",\"subGrade\":\"FF\"}," +
            "{\"subName\":\"EG\",\"subCode\":\"1009\",\"subCredit\":\"6\",\"subGrade\":\"CC\"}," +
            "{\"subName\":\"M-4\",\"subCode\":\"1009\",\"subCredit\":\"6\",\"subGrade\":\"CD\"}," +
            "{\"subName\":\"AE\",\"subCode\":\"103309\",\"subCredit\":\"6\",\"subGrade\":\"CD\"}," +
            "{\"subName\":\"EG-1\",\"subCode\":\"11119\",\"subCredit\":\"6\",\"subGrade\":\"CD\"}," +
            "{\"subName\":\"AE\",\"subCode\":\"8876\",\"subCredit\":\"6\",\"subGrade\":\"FF\"}," +
            "{\"SPI\":\"2.5\",\"CPI\":\"6.67\"}]," +
            "\"3\":[{\"subName\":\"M-3\",\"subCode\":\"111009\",\"subCredit\":\"6\",\"subGrade\":\"AA\"}," +
            "{\"subName\":\"BE\",\"subCode\":\"1009\",\"subCredit\":\"6\",\"subGrade\":\"AB\"}," +
            "{\"subName\":\"DLD\",\"subCode\":\"1009\",\"subCredit\":\"6\",\"subGrade\":\"BB\"}," +
            "{\"subName\":\"NCS\",\"subCode\":\"1009\",\"subCredit\":\"6\",\"subGrade\":\"BC\"}," +
            "{\"subName\":\"M-4\",\"subCode\":\"1009\",\"subCredit\":\"6\",\"subGrade\":\"CC\"}," +
            "{\"subName\":\"AE\",\"subCode\":\"103309\",\"subCredit\":\"6\",\"subGrade\":\"CD\"}," +
            "{\"SPI\":\"6.50\",\"CPI\":\"0.67\"}]," +
            "\"4\":[{\"subName\":\"AAS\",\"subCode\":\"111009\",\"subCredit\":\"6\",\"subGrade\":\"AB\"}," +
            "{\"subName\":\"C++\",\"subCode\":\"1009\",\"subCredit\":\"6\",\"subGrade\":\"AB\"}," +
            "{\"subName\":\"Management-1\",\"subCode\":\"1009\",\"subCredit\":\"6\",\"subGrade\":\"AB\"}," +
            "{\"subName\":\"EG\",\"subCode\":\"1009\",\"subCredit\":\"6\",\"subGrade\":\"AB\"}," +
            "{\"subName\":\"M-4\",\"subCode\":\"1009\",\"subCredit\":\"6\",\"subGrade\":\"AB\"}," +
            "{\"subName\":\"AE\",\"subCode\":\"103309\",\"subCredit\":\"6\",\"subGrade\":\"DD\"}," +
            "{\"SPI\":\"9.50\",\"CPI\":\"5.67\"}]," +
            "\"5\":[{\"subName\":\"WAD\",\"subCode\":\"111022209\",\"subCredit\":\"6\",\"subGrade\":\"FF\"}," +
            "{\"subName\":\"AES\",\"subCode\":\"703309\",\"subCredit\":\"6\",\"subGrade\":\"DD\"}," +
            "{\"SPI\":\"5.50\",\"CPI\":\"5.67\",\"CGPA\":\"5.67\"}]," +
            "\"6\":[{\"subName\":\"SP\",\"subCode\":\"66622209\",\"subCredit\":\"6\",\"subGrade\":\"FF\"}," +
            "{\"subName\":\"Parallel\",\"subCode\":\"66622209\",\"subCredit\":\"6\",\"subGrade\":\"AB\"}," +
            "{\"subName\":\"Java\",\"subCode\":\"66622209\",\"subCredit\":\"6\",\"subGrade\":\"AB\"}," +
            "{\"subName\":\"COA\",\"subCode\":\"66622209\",\"subCredit\":\"6\",\"subGrade\":\"AB\"}," +
            "{\"subName\":\"Management\",\"subCode\":\"66622209\",\"subCredit\":\"6\",\"subGrade\":\"FF\"}," +
            "{\"subName\":\"TOC\",\"subCode\":\"703309\",\"subCredit\":\"6\",\"subGrade\":\"DD\"}," +
            "{\"SPI\":\"5.50\",\"CPI\":\"5.67\",\"CGPA\":\"6.07\"}]," +
            "\"7\":[{\"subName\":\"CD\",\"subCode\":\"12522209\",\"subCredit\":\"6\",\"subGrade\":\"AB\"}," +
            "{\"subName\":\"WCMP\",\"subCode\":\"12522209\",\"subCredit\":\"6\",\"subGrade\":\"AB\"}," +
            "{\"subName\":\"SP\",\"subCode\":\"12522209\",\"subCredit\":\"6\",\"subGrade\":\"AB\"}," +
            "{\"subName\":\"Advance Java\",\"subCode\":\"703309\",\"subCredit\":\"6\",\"subGrade\":\"FF\"}," +
            "{\"SPI\":\"8.90\",\"CPI\":\"6.09\",\"CGPA\":\"7.77\"}]," +
            "\"8\":[{\"subName\":\"Android\",\"subCode\":\77022209\",\"subCredit\":\"6\",\"subGrade\":\"AB\"}," +
            "{\"subName\":\"PP\",\"subCode\":2209\",\"subCredit\":\"6\",\"subGrade\":\"BB\"}," +
            "{\"subName\":\"DS\",\"subCode\":\"7309\",\"subCredit\":\"6\",\"subGrade\":\"DD\"}," +
            "{\"SPI\":\"5.70\",\"CPI\":\"5.97\",\"CGPA\":\"6.85\"}]}";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params1) {

        String key;

        Iterator<String> iter;

        int length;

  /*  List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(c.getResources().getString(R.string.keyUsername), Utility.getUsername(c)));
    JSONParser jp=new JSONParser();
    //jp.makeHttpRequest(c.getResources().getString(R.string.server_name)+ c.getResources().getString(R.string.login_file), "POST", params);
  */ //Todo : delete comment when data is come from server.

        try {

            jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsondata);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        iter = jsonObject.keys();

        semesterArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        while (iter.hasNext()) {

            key = iter.next();
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray(key);

                length = jsonArray.length();

                ArrayList<SubjectDetails> saveSubDetailsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

                Semester semDetail = new Semester();

                semDetail.setSemester(key);

                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    SubjectDetails subDetails = new SubjectDetails();

                    if (i == length - 1) {

                        Float spi = Float.valueOf(jsonObject1.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.server_key_result_SPI)));
                        Float cpi = Float.valueOf(jsonObject1.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.server_key_result_CPI)));

                        semDetail.setSpi(spi);
                        semDetail.setCpi(cpi);

                        if (key.equals("5") || key.equals("6") || key.equals("7") || key.equals("8")) {
                            Float cgpi = Float.valueOf(jsonObject1.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.server_key_result_CGPA)));
                            semDetail.setCgpi(cgpi);
                        }
                    } else {

                        String subname = jsonObject1.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.server_key_result_subName));
                        String subcode = jsonObject1.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.server_key_result_subCode));
                        String subcredit = jsonObject1.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.server_key_result_subCredit));
                        String subgrade = jsonObject1.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.server_key_result_subGrade));

                        subDetails.setSubname(subname);
                        subDetails.setSubcode(subcode);
                        subDetails.setSubcredit(subcredit);
                        subDetails.setSubgrade(subgrade);

                        saveSubDetailsArrayList.add(subDetails);

                        semDetail.setGetSubjectDetails(saveSubDetailsArrayList);
                    }
                }
                semesterArrayList.add(semDetail);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        ListView lv = (ListView) newView.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        lv.setAdapter(new ShowResultAdapter(semesterArrayList, context));
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

and this is my Adapter class...

public class ShowResultAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
ArrayList<Semester> semesterArrayList;

Context c;

LinearLayout linearHeader;

ShowResultAdapter(ArrayList<Semester> saveDetails, Context context)

{
    semesterArrayList = saveDetails;
    c = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return semesterArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;

    LinearLayout linearSub;

    LinearLayout linearSpiCpiCgpa;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_result_adapter, null);
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linear);

    TextView sem = new TextView(c);
    sem.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    sem.setTextSize(20);
    sem.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 10);
    sem.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    sem.setText(c.getResources().getString(R.string.result_Semester) + " " + ":" + " " + semesterArrayList.get(position).getSemester());
    sem.setPaintFlags(Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);

    linearLayout.addView(sem);

    linearHeader = new LinearLayout(c);
    linearHeader.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    linearHeader.setWeightSum(4);

    TextView name = new TextView(c);
    setHeader(name, c.getResources().getString(R.string.server_key_result_subName));
    linearHeader.addView(name);

    TextView code = new TextView(c);
    setHeader(code, c.getResources().getString(R.string.server_key_result_subCode));
    linearHeader.addView(code);

    TextView credit = new TextView(c);
    setHeader(credit, c.getResources().getString(R.string.server_key_result_subCredit));
    linearHeader.addView(credit);

    TextView grade = new TextView(c);
    setHeader(grade, c.getResources().getString(R.string.server_key_result_subGrade));
    linearHeader.addView(grade);

    linearLayout.addView(linearHeader);

    if (semesterArrayList.get(position).getSemester().equals("1") || semesterArrayList.get(position).getSemester().equals("2") || semesterArrayList.get(position).getSemester().equals("3") || semesterArrayList.get(position).getSemester().equals("4")) {

        linearSpiCpiCgpa = new LinearLayout(c);
        linearSpiCpiCgpa.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        linearSpiCpiCgpa.setWeightSum(4);

        for (int i = 0; i < semesterArrayList.get(position).getGetSubjectDetails().size(); i++)

        {
            linearSub = new LinearLayout(c);
            linearSub.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 4));
            linearSub.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            TextView subname = new TextView(c);
            setSubject(subname);

            TextView subcode = new TextView(c);
            setSubject(subcode);

            TextView subcredit = new TextView(c);
            setSubject(subcredit);

            TextView subgrade = new TextView(c);
            setSubject(subgrade);
            subgrade.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD));

            subname.setText(semesterArrayList.get(position).getGetSubjectDetails().get(i).getSubname());

            subcode.setText(semesterArrayList.get(position).getGetSubjectDetails().get(i).getSubcode());

            subcredit.setText(semesterArrayList.get(position).getGetSubjectDetails().get(i).getSubcredit());

            subgrade.setText(semesterArrayList.get(position).getGetSubjectDetails().get(i).getSubgrade());

            if (semesterArrayList.get(position).getGetSubjectDetails().get(i).getSubgrade().equals("FF")) {
                subgrade.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
            }
            linearSub.addView(subname);
            linearSub.addView(subcode);
            linearSub.addView(subcredit);
            linearSub.addView(subgrade);

            linearLayout.addView(linearSub);

        }

        TextView spi = new TextView(c);
        setSpiCpiCgpa(spi);

        TextView cpi = new TextView(c);
        setSpiCpiCgpa(cpi);

        spi.setText(c.getResources().getString(R.string.server_key_result_SPI) + " " + ":" + " " + semesterArrayList.get(position).getSpi());
        cpi.setText(c.getResources().getString(R.string.server_key_result_CPI) + " " + ":" + " " + semesterArrayList.get(position).getCpi());

        linearSpiCpiCgpa.addView(spi);
        linearSpiCpiCgpa.addView(cpi);

        linearLayout.addView(linearSpiCpiCgpa);
    } else {

        linearSpiCpiCgpa = new LinearLayout(c);
        linearSpiCpiCgpa.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        linearSpiCpiCgpa.setWeightSum(6);

        for (int i = 0; i < semesterArrayList.get(position).getGetSubjectDetails().size(); i++)

        {
            linearSub = new LinearLayout(c);
            linearSub.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            linearSub.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 4));

            TextView subname = new TextView(c);
            setSubject(subname);

            TextView subcode = new TextView(c);
            setSubject(subcode);

            TextView subcredit = new TextView(c);
            setSubject(subcredit);

            TextView subgrade = new TextView(c);
            setSubject(subgrade);

            subname.setText(semesterArrayList.get(position).getGetSubjectDetails().get(i).getSubname());

            subcode.setText(semesterArrayList.get(position).getGetSubjectDetails().get(i).getSubcode());

            subcredit.setText(semesterArrayList.get(position).getGetSubjectDetails().get(i).getSubcredit());

            subgrade.setText(semesterArrayList.get(position).getGetSubjectDetails().get(i).getSubgrade());

            linearSub.addView(subname);
            linearSub.addView(subcode);
            linearSub.addView(subcredit);
            linearSub.addView(subgrade);

            linearLayout.addView(linearSub);
        }

        TextView spi = new TextView(c);
        setSpiCpiCgpa(spi);

        TextView cpi = new TextView(c);
        setSpiCpiCgpa(cpi);

        TextView cgpi = new TextView(c);
        setSpiCpiCgpa(cgpi);

        spi.setText(c.getResources().getString(R.string.server_key_result_SPI) + " " + ":" + " " + semesterArrayList.get(position).getSpi());
        cpi.setText(c.getResources().getString(R.string.server_key_result_CPI) + " " + ":" + " " + semesterArrayList.get(position).getCpi());
        cgpi.setText(c.getResources().getString(R.string.server_key_result_CGPA) + " " + ":" + " " + semesterArrayList.get(position).getCgpi());

        linearSpiCpiCgpa.addView(spi);
        linearSpiCpiCgpa.addView(cpi);
        linearSpiCpiCgpa.addView(cgpi);

        linearLayout.addView(linearSpiCpiCgpa);
    }
    return view;
}

public void setHeader(TextView txtObj, String setText) {
    txtObj.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 10);
    txtObj.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    txtObj.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.whiteborder);
    txtObj.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    txtObj.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#80000000"));
    txtObj.setTextSize(16);
    txtObj.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD));
    txtObj.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));

    txtObj.setText(setText);

}

public void setSubject(TextView txtObj) {
    txtObj.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1));
    txtObj.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    txtObj.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.resultborder);
    txtObj.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    txtObj.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

}

public void setSpiCpiCgpa(TextView txtObj) {
    txtObj.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    txtObj.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    txtObj.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    txtObj.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.resultborder);
    txtObj.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD));
    txtObj.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 2));
}
```

}

Comment: put more code `AsyncTask` class

Comment: where is the code??? where is AsyncTask??? :D

Comment: problem is not is Asynctask , problem is this is right way or not to call Asynctask in Fragment class ?

Comment: You need to pass the Fragment class to your AsynClass. This way, you can access the `onPostExecute` method of your Fragment from your AsyncClass.

Comment: Mornor can you please tell me how can i do

Comment: means you are unable to call Asynctask ? is this right ?

Comment: Yes Amit because it is going to other line which is return newView but this call is not go to the Asynctask i get null view.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't inflate your `View`. How do you expect it to not return `null`?
You should inflate the `View` in `onCreateView()` rather than in `onPostExecute()`

Change it like this.

```
ShowResultAdapter adapter = null;    

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.inflaterView = inflater;
    this.containerView = container;
    context = container.getContext();
    newView = inflaterView.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
    lv = (ListView) newView.findViewById(R.id.listview); // Define lv at class level
    adapter = new ShowResultAdapter(semesterArrayList, getActivity())
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    new StudentResultAsyncTask().execute();
    return newView;
}
```

In your `onPostExecute()` method do this

```
protected void onPostExecute(String s) 
{ 
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    pDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: IMO it would be even better to define the `ListView` and its adapter in `onCreateView()` as well, and only update the adapter's data and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in `onPostExecute()`

Comment: Where is the reference to newview in the StudentResulyAsyncTask.

Comment: @PPartisan: I agree, let me update it. Thanks for pointing that out.  :)

Comment: you are right sir but in my case my data is come out after doinbackground if i call my xml before calling asynctask i also got null view , i am also trying this, please suggest me other thing sir.

Comment: @ChandanParlecha Are you querying a database in `doInBackground()`? If so, what does the `getCount()` method look like in your adapter? You should arrange it so that a `null` data set is equal to an empty (i.e. 0 row) `ListView`. Alternatively, instatiate `semesterArrayList` immediately so it is not null. May fix it. If not, code for  `ShowResultAdapter` and `StudentResultAsyncTask` in your OP will help debug.

Comment: i am update my code please see my code and suggest me.

Comment: @ChandanParlecha: Did you try my code? It should work even if you get data using `AsyncTask`

Comment: i get my arraylist from doinbackground , so how can i call before this.

Comment: @ChandanParlecha: Can you at least try? Doesn't matter where the data come from. Please notice in my code that once data is there I am updating the listview.

Comment: yes sir i am try, but lv.notifyDataSetChanged(); is not work for me.

Comment: Oh, my bad. please try now.

Comment: i think only notify() , or notifyAll() is use for this ?

Comment: I have update the code. `notifyDataSetChanged()` is supposed to be called on adapter not listview.

Comment: Method remains same. Its the object instance. Read my complete code, don't you see any change?

Comment: yes sir i am tried , but i got nullpointer exception on adapter class beacuse my arralist is come from doinbackground and when i call lv.setAdaper its call my adapter class and i got null value of that.

Comment: now telling me if there is any other way to call asynctask class within a Fragment.

Comment: @ChandanParlecha It sounds from your explanation as if this is simply caused by `semesterArrayList` being `null`. If so, try out my answer in addition to Rohit5k2's if you haven't already, or instantiate `semesterArrayList` in your declaration: `ArrayList semesterArrayList<Semester> = new ArrayList<>();` Failing that, add your error log to your OP.

Comment: no bro i am debug and see my semarraylist is have a data , and problem is not with my data problem is my new StudentResultAsyncTask().execute(); is not call and my postexecute methos is not call and it will return my view.

Comment: so please tell me how can i call my asynctask and access my all method in fragment class.

Answer (score 0):

Following from the suggestions made by Rohit5k2, alter your `getcount()` method in your adapter to respond to `null` data:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    if (semesterArrayList == null) {
        return 0;
    }    
    return semesterArrayList.size();
}
```

When you first call `setAdapter()` on the `ListView` in Rohit's answer, the data will be null as it is only populated in `onPostExecute()`. However, if you make the above adjustment, then all will happen is that the list will be empty until the data is populated.